# TranslateAnimation анимация объекта в цикле и случайным местоположением

Tags: java, android, анимация

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать повторяющийся цикл анимации объекта? В моем приложении есть готовая анимация созданная при помощи TranslateAnimation. Объект спускается вниз по экрану из случайного места по оси Х. Как реализовать в приложении возможность повторять цикл анимации объекта с нового местоположения по оси Х? В идеале хотелось бы получить множество объектов с рандомных мест по оси Х одновременно.

Мой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageViews;
AnimationDrawable imagesAnimation;

int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

Random r = new Random();
int sX1 = r.nextInt(width);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    animation();
}

public void animation() {
    imageViews = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    imageViews.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_sw);
    imagesAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViews.getBackground();
    TranslateAnimation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(sX1, sX1, 0.0f, height);
    animation1.setDuration(5000);
    animation1.setRepeatCount(0);
    animation1.setFillAfter(true);
    imageViews.startAnimation(animation1);
    imagesAnimation.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на уникальность, но у себя сделал так:

```
TranslateAnimation animation_right;
boolean start_animation_right = false;
ImageView imageView_right; // картинка

animation_right = new TranslateAnimation(700, 750, 0, 0);
animation_right.setDuration(500);
animation_right.setFillAfter(true);
animation_right.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
animation_right.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());


if (*условие*) {
     if (!start_animation_right) {
         imageView_right.startAnimation(animation_right);
         start_animation_right = true;
     }
} else {
     if (start_animation_right) {
         imageView_right.clearAnimation();
         start_animation_right = false;
     }
}
```

На экране у меня пролетает вспышка из угла в угол, пока выполняется условие